# Как сделать анимацию которая повторяется один раз?

Tags: вёрстка, css3, анимация, css-animation

Мне надо сделать анимацию размытия элемента `blur(3px);`, это смешно, но я не смог найти решения в гугле. Анимация упорно хочет вернутся назад и не хочет "зависнуть на достигнутом результате".

Все, что бы я ни делал, все равно приводит к тому, что анимация возвращается обратно на `blur(0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для управления этим поведением есть атрибут `animation-fill-mode`. Вам нужно установить его в `forwards` (по-умолчанию - `none`, т.е. в конце анимации элемент возвращается к начальному состоянию, и стили, указанные в анимации, к нему не применяются).

Не забудьте про префиксы, если не пользуетесь автопрефиксерами.
Подробно свойство расписано тут: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp